# Reference Shell Script Variable in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile

I have a `config.sh`:

```
IMAGE_NAME="back_end"
APP_PORT=80
PUBLIC_PORT=8080
```

and a `build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh

echo "Image name is: ${IMAGE_NAME}"

sudo docker build -t ${IMAGE_NAME} .
```

and a `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh

# Expose ports and run
sudo docker run -it \
        -p $PUBLIC_PORT:$APP_PORT \
        --name $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_NAME
```

and finally, a `Dockerfile`:

```
...
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:${APP_PORT}", "main:app"]
```

I'd like to be able to reference the `APP_PORT` variable in my `config.sh` within the `Dockerfile` as shown above.  However, what I have does not work and it complains: `Error: ${APP_PORT} is not a valid port number`.  So it's not interpreting `APP_PORT` as a variable.  Is there a way to reference the variables within `config.sh` from within the `Dockerfile`?

Thanks!

### EDIT: New Files based on suggested solutions (still don't work)

I have a `config.sh`:

```
IMAGE_NAME="back_end"
APP_PORT=80
PUBLIC_PORT=8080
```

and a `build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh

echo "Image name is: ${IMAGE_NAME}"

sudo docker build --build-arg APP_PORT="${APP_PORT}" -t "${IMAGE_NAME}" .
```

and a `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh

# Expose ports and run
sudo docker run -it \
        -p $PUBLIC_PORT:$APP_PORT \
        --name $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_NAME
```

and finally, a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:buster

LABEL maintainer="..."

ARG APP_PORT
#ENV PORT $APP_PORT
ENV APP_PORT=${APP_PORT}

#RUN echo "$PORT"

# Install gunicorn & falcon
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Add demo app
COPY ./app /app
COPY ./config.sh /app/config.sh
WORKDIR /app

RUN ls -a

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:${APP_PORT}", "main:app"]
```

`run.sh` still fails and reports: `Error: '${APP_PORT} is not a valid port number.'`

Comment: A Docker container runs in an isolated network environment, and the `docker run -p` option lets you arbitrarily remap the port on the host.  Do you have a use case for needing to change the container-private port number at run time, or can you hard-code it in both the Dockerfile and your script?

Comment: Simply to not have to remember to change the port in multiple places if I ever need to in the future.

Comment: You don't need to change it in multiple places regardless. Pick a value, keep that value forever, remap only the _external port that internal port is mapped to_ if it needs to change. There's no reason to make the internal port match the external one, so only the external one ever needs to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a variable in Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM python:buster

LABEL maintainer="..."

ARG APP_PORT
ENV APP_PORT=${APP_PORT}


# Install gunicorn & falcon
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Add demo app
COPY ./app /app
COPY ./config.sh /app/config.sh
WORKDIR /app

CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$APP_PORT main:app     # NOTE! without separating with ["",""]
```

Pass it as `build-arg`, e.g. in your `build.sh`:

**Note!** Passing build argument is only necessary when it is used for building docker image. You use it on `CMD` and one can omit passing it during building docker image.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh

echo "Image name is: ${IMAGE_NAME}"

sudo docker build --build-arg APP_PORT="${APP_PORT}" -t "${IMAGE_NAME}" .
# sudo docker build --build-arg APP_PORT=80 -t back_end .           -> You may omit using config.sh and directly define the value of variables
```

and pass value of `$APP_PORT` in `run.sh` as well when starting the container:

```
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh

# Expose ports and run
sudo docker run -it \
        -e APP_PORT=$APP_PORT \
        -p $PUBLIC_PORT:$APP_PORT \
        --name $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_NAME
```

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work.  I get this message after running `run.sh`: `Error: ${APP_PORT} is not a valid port number`.  Additionally, I tried without the braces on `APP_PORT` as well as another attempt that put a `ENV APP_PORT $APP_PORT` in the Dockerfile before the `CMD` but still get an error that it seems to literally interpret the variable instead of expanding it.

Comment: I can start docker container with your ```run.sh``` script. Does the error comes from executed sh script or docker container?

Comment: How can I tell the source of the error?  At the moment, it just prints the above error message in terminal without any further decoration after running `run.sh`.  If you could post the complete versions of the files you're using (just so that I can be sure I haven't introduced any regressions with my hurried trials) and I can get them running, I'm happy to accept your solution as the "correct one".

Comment: I think your original question was answered here, i.e. referencing environment variable to Dockerfile by passing it as ```--build-arg```.  You may accept the answer if you could build docker image by passing a variable with ```--build-arg```. For the error on running docker container I would kindly ask you to open a new question and would by happy to support you.

Comment: P.s. I do not have any difference on my scripts from one you posted on question description. Alternatively you may start your docker just from commandline as e.g. ```sudo docker run -it -p 8080:80 --name back_end back_end``` to make sure you built docker image correctly.

Comment: I assume the docker image was not build correctly. In ```run.sh``` you run docker container not in detached mode and container error directed to terminal. Can you please update and post your complete Dockerfile and scripts you use.

Comment: @JohnCast Please check the answer, I have updated it and added ```ENV APP_PORT=${APP_PORT}```.  ```ARG``` is only during the docker build available and not after, i.e. not available in ```CMD```, that's why you getting an error ```Error: ${APP_PORT} is not a valid port number``` from container.

Comment: Please see my updated question under `EDIT`.  I believe I have tried what you describe but it still gives the above error.

Comment: @JohnCast thanks for addition further details. I could finally reproduce the error and it came from gunicorn. I have adjusted CMD in ```Dockerfile``` as  ```CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$APP_PORT main:app```, and added ```-e APP_PORT=$APP_PORT \``` to docker run command in ```run.sh``` to pass the value of APP_PORT. It works all fine for me now, please test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248053/discussion-between-m19v-and-john-cast).

Answer (score 0):

You need a shell to replace environment variables and when your CMD is in *exec form*, there's no shell.

If you use the *shell form*, there is a shell and you can use environment variables.

```
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:${APP_PORT} main:app
```

Read here for more information on the two forms of the CMD statement: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: Thanks @Hans, however I think I'm still missing something.  When I try your suggested version of CMD and copy the `config.sh` to the working directory, the CMD doesn't seem able to find the variable.  See my post under EDIT for the specific changes I made.  Thanks!